Kotlin - Storage.reference.child("user/image/image.pnj").downloadUrl won't trigger
I was trying to use downloadUrl function of Firebase and add both addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener. The program ran without error but the function didn't trigger.
val test = storageRef.child("user/image/1000008988.jpg")
        test.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {uri ->
          uris.add(uri)
          Log.d("UploadSuccess", uris.toString())
        }
          .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("UploadSuccess", uris.toString())
          }

I know it doesn't trigger because log cat does not have the log.d that I put into the listener.
Any clue?
I tried getDownloadUrl() but no hope as well.
Edit: Below is the logging that I received when I tried to call the function to display the image, which uses the uri collected from downloadUrl
2024-08-15 11:56:21.386 29961-29961 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.makeitso                 D  Compat change id reported: 289878283; UID 10485; state: ENABLED
2024-08-15 11:56:21.535 29961-29961 WindowOnBackDispatcher  com.example.makeitso                 W  OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
                                                                                                    Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
2024-08-15 11:56:21.688 29961-29961 BLASTBufferQueue_Java   com.example.makeitso                 I  update, w= 636 h= 576 mName = ViewRootImpl@e8673b3[Pop-Up Window] mNativeObject= 0xb40000750e0aae90 sc.mNativeObject= 0xb40000762e0a0790 format= -3 caller= android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateBlastSurfaceIfNeeded:3017 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:10131 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4110 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:3288 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:11344 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1689 
2024-08-15 11:56:21.688 29961-29961 ViewRootIm...Up Window] com.example.makeitso                 I  Relayout returned: old=(516,381,1056,861) new=(516,381,1056,861) relayoutAsync=true req=(540,480)0 dur=1 res=0x0 s={true 0xb40000755e09e2a0} ch=false seqId=0
2024-08-15 11:56:21.689 29961-29961 ViewRootIm...Up Window] com.example.makeitso                 I  registerCallbackForPendingTransactions
2024-08-15 11:56:21.690 29961-30006 StorageUtil             com.example.makeitso                 W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
2024-08-15 11:56:21.691 29961-30050 ViewRootIm...Up Window] com.example.makeitso                 I  mWNT: t=0xb4000074ee0c2350 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb40000750e0aae90 fn= 10 mRenderHdrSdrRatio=1.0 caller= android.view.ViewRootImpl$6.onFrameDraw:5635 android.view.ViewRootImpl$2.onFrameDraw:2146 android.view.ThreadedRenderer$1.onFrameDraw:792 
2024-08-15 11:56:21.702 29961-30006 TrafficStats            com.example.makeitso                 D  tagSocket(6) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-08-15 11:56:22.383  1667-1667  audit                   auditd                               E  type=1400 audit(1723740982.381:3611555): avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=29961 comm=4D6561737572656D656E7420576F72 path="/data/data/com.example.makeitso/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db" dev="dm-56" ino=814332 ioctlcmd=0xf522 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c229,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c229,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-S901U_12_0001 audit_filtered
2024-08-15 11:56:22.760 29961-29961 AndroidRuntime          com.example.makeitso                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.makeitso, PID: 29961
                                                                                                    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 returned because my function returned a list of Uri.
As you can see in the log above, no Log has the tag "UploadSuccess", which should be there if downloadUrl is triggered.
I also allow public read and write for my project in Rules for Storage, and ensure all the libraries are up-to-date.
      allow read, write: if true;


Do you have any logging that confirms that downloadUrl gets accessed at all? If so, could you edit the question to share that code?

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Hi @DougStevenson, thank you for your response. I have uploaded the log that I received when I was trying to run the function. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Did you add your own logging that confirms that downloadUrl gets accessed at all?

Hi @DougStevenson, I'm not sure what you mean here. Do you mean that there should be an event listener for when downloadUrl gets accessed that has the logging? I included the code that has the logging when downloadUrl being triggered, and that is the only logging that I have in my program. Did I do it in the wrong way?
